# How to access form date fields in template

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates, django-1.8

I want to render a form in Django. In normal case, you access fields like this:

```
{{ form.name }}
```

But I'm using date field with `SelectDateWidget` widget. This widget has different field for year,month and day.

How could I access these fields one by one?

`{{ form.date.year }}` or

`{{ form.date.0 }}` or

`{{ form.date_year }}` etc. doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
{{ form.date|date:"Y" }}
```

You can take a look at the complete docs here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/